# How to change textview default color (Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)

Tags: android

I am trying to understand the theming and styling system of Android and basically attempt to do the simplest thing - change the default color of TextView texts.

According to the source code of TextView the default style would be:

```
<item name="textViewStyle">@style/Widget.TextView</item>
```

Looking at this style I discover the following:

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">
    <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    ....
</style>
```

It seems that the default textAppearance is set to textAppearanceSmall (from the theme).

I look into themes.xml for the referenced `textAppearanceSmall` and find this:

```
<item name="textAppearanceSmall">@style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
```

Aha - it references this TextAppearance.Small:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Ok, we are getting somewhere - maybe? By default TextView uses the color "textColorSecondary".

First immediate question: Why is it references so weirdly? (questionmark but not like '?attr/textColorSecondary')?

I go back to the themes.xml file and discover this:

```
<item name="textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text_dark</item>
```

At this point I am  pretty sure that I have to override `textColorSecondary` in my custom AppTheme like so:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00CC00</item>
</style>
```

This does of course not work... the question is - why?

BTW: All the files I am looking at (theme.xml & styles.xml) reside in my Android SDK directory:

```
C:\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-26\data\res\values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```